# using the 'this' pointer inside a std::function prototype

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

to my understanding a member function is different to a normal function because there is an additional `this` pointer parameter.

So my idea is to make is make the following member template function to one of my classes:

```
template <class T>
void    ApplyFunction(function<void(vector<int>&, T)> fun, T val);
```

and then I will use it inside one of my classes like:

```
Thing.ApplyFunction(myMethod, this);
```

and `Thing` will use the `myMethod` from my current class instance.

---

A lot of this code is guesswork so I would like some clarification as to if this would work. Also not sure which way round it is:

```
void    ApplyFunction(function<void(vector<int>&, T)> fun, T val);
```

or

```
void    ApplyFunction(T val, function<void(vector<int>&, T)> fun);
```

---

A code sample describing why I might want something like this:

```
void    ClassA::callbackMethod(vector<int> &array)
{
        //I can edit the array here
}

void    ClassA::someMethod(void)
{
    ClassB B;

    B.ApplyFunction(callbackMethod, this);

    //now whenever B wants to edit the array, it can by using callbackMethod

    B.ComplicatedStuff(); // B uses the callbackMethod multiple times here
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to solve exactly? `this->myMethod(args)` should work just fine (probably `myMethod(args)` too).

Comment: the class which `Thing` belongs to will use the member function of some other class as its function pointer argument.

Comment: std::function is a class template, conceptually has nothing to do with member pointer.

Comment: What's the value in calling `B.ApplyFunction` before calling `B.ComplicatedStuff`?  Why not pass the function directly to `B.ComplicatedStuff`?

Comment: perhaps there is `B.ComplicatedStuff` and `B.ComplicatederStuff`, but it would still boil down to the same question either way

Comment: You are looking for `std::invoke`

Comment: @PasserBy could you elaborate on how I would use it to achieve similar results

Comment: @PasserBy that's C++17

Comment: @TheoWalton `std::invoke(classmemberponter, classinstance, arguments... )` would pass pointer to `classinstance` as `this` to the `memberpointer`. But i think that storing lambda might be more transparent... both have issue of object' life

Comment: What does `ApplyFunction` do?

Comment: @Yakk I want it to call the function one time, and then store it so that it can be called other times

Comment: @theo how do you intend to store the T?  Do you need the T other than for calling the function?

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you are just planning to invoke a method, and you don't need to store the callable. If that is the case you should not use `std::function` but simply take a callable as a template parameter.

```
template <class T>
void ApplyFunction(T&& func) {
    func(/*pass in your vector here*/);
}
```

With that you can you can then call it from `A` by passing in a lambda.

```
void    ClassA::someMethod(void)
{
    ClassB B;
    B.ApplyFunction([&](std::vector<int>& vec){
        // do stuff with vec here
        // or call a member function
        callbackMethod(vec);
        vec.push_back(2);
    });
}
```

This will be faster since passing by template parameter like this gives almost no additional cost from just a normal function call. If the function is inline it can be as cheap as just calling a member function.

`std::function` is a type-erased wrapper for any callable and comes with overhead, only use it if you need to store the callable for later use.

**Edit**

If you like to store the function, you don't need a template, you can simply take a `std::function` as parameter in `ApplyFunction`.

```
void ApplyFunction(std::function<void(std::vector<int>&)> func) {
    //Store it, call it now or call it later.
    m_func = func;
    m_func(/*pass in your vector here*/);
}
```

Call it the same way, with a lambda.
Using a lambda like this is the preferred method when binding a member function to an instance. Instead of passing `this` separately it's better to wrap it in a lambda and get it for free so to speak.

Comment: upvoted but unfortunately I would like to store the function inside class B - so ill hold out on accepting. Thanks though

Comment: @TheoWalton I see, added an update to show how you would do that.